Time dependence of momentum operator in QFT
In QFT in flat spacetime, we want to have a representation of the Poincare algebra on the Hilbert space $\mathscr H$ of states. This is due to the Wightman axioms. So there should exist operators $M_{\mu\nu}$ and $P_\mu$ on $\mathscr H$ that satisfy the Poincare algebra. Those operators need to be constant, i.e. no functions of space and time.
The momentum operators are usually constructed as the charges associated to infinitesimal translations. Equivalently the momentum operators are defined by integrating the energy-momentum tensor operator over a spacelike hyperplane $\Sigma_t$ of constant time, so
$$ P^\mu(t) = \int_{\Sigma_t}dS_\nu(x)T^{\mu\nu}(x).$$
If the energy-momentum tensor were conserved, i.e. $\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu} (x)  \equiv 0$ (so the operator on the left is identical to the zero operator), then $P^\mu(t)$ would be constant in time.
However, the conservation equation of the energy-momentum tensor only holds as an operator equation, so
$$ \partial_\mu\langle  T^{\mu\nu}(x)~\cdots~\rangle = 0,$$
where the other operator insertions into the correlation function are not located at $x$. This implies that in general $\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}(x)$ is not the zero operator, so in general we get$$\frac{d}{dt}P^\mu(t) \neq 0.$$
My question is: How are the notions of the time-dependent momentum operator defined above and the time-independent momentum operator, which is assumed to exist in the Wightman axioms, related?
EDIT: Let me clarify what my problem is exactly. The Schwinger-Dyson equation for the energy-momentum tensor is
$$ \begin{split} \partial_\nu \langle  T^{\mu\nu}(x)&O_1(x_1)\cdots O_n(x_n)\rangle  \\ = i&\sum_{j=1}^n \delta^{(d)}(x-x_j) \partial_j^\mu\langle O_1(x_1)\cdots O_n(x_n)\rangle.\end{split}$$
Now assume $P^\nu(t)$ was constant in time, so $P^\mu(t_2)-P^\mu(t_1)\equiv 0$. Let $V_{t_1t_2}$ be the volume between $\Sigma_{t_1}$ and $\Sigma_{t_2}$. Then we would need
$$\begin{split}0 &\stackrel{!}{=} \big\langle (P^\mu(t_2)-P^\mu(t_1)) O_n(x_1)\cdots O_n(x_n)\big\rangle \\
&= \langle \int_{\Sigma_{t_2}} dS_\nu(x) T^{\mu\nu}(x) O_1(x_1)\dots O_n(x_n)\rangle -  \langle \int_{\Sigma_{t_1}} dS_\nu(x) T^{\mu\nu}(x) O_1(x_1)\dots O_n(x_n)\rangle \\
&=  \langle \int_{\partial V_{t_1t_2}} dS_\nu(x) T^{\mu\nu}(x)O_1(x_1)\dots O_n(x_n)\rangle \\
&= \int_{V_{t_1t_2}} d^dx~\partial_\nu\langle T^{\mu\nu}(x)O_1(x_1)\dots O_n(x_n)\rangle \\
&= \int_{V_{t_1t_2}} d^dx~i\sum_{j=1}^n \delta^{(d)}(x-x_j) \partial_j^\mu\langle O_1(x_1)\cdots O_n(x_n)\rangle \\
&= i \sum_{x_j \in V_{t_1t_2}} \partial_j^\mu \langle O_1(x_1)\cdots O_n(x_n)\rangle.
\end{split}$$
So we get (after possibly renaming indices),
$$ 0 \stackrel{!}{=} \sum_{j=1}^m \partial_j^\mu\langle O_1(x_1) \cdots O_n(x_n)\rangle, \quad (*)$$
where $m$ is the number of operators inside $V_{t_1t_2}$. If $m=n$, the expression would equal the one for $t_2\rightarrow \infty$ and $t_1\rightarrow -\infty$ and if we demand the energy-momentum tensor to vanish at infinite times, the equality $(*)$ holds. This is then basically the Ward identity for the momentum operator. However for $m \neq n$ (so operator insertions at times less than $t_1$ or bigger than $t_2$), $(*)$ does not hold in general as far as I can see. Therefore, assuming
$$ \frac{d}{dt} P^\mu(t) = 0$$
leads to a contradiction.

I really dont understand what is your problem with these. Don't you see that once you have integrate $\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}(x)$ over the spacelike hyperplane, then even though it is not the zero operator, this integral will always be zero, and thus the momentum operator is conserved.

@naturallyInconsistent you do not integrate $\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}$ over a spacelike hyperplane, just $T^{\mu\nu}$. You need to integrate $\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}$ over a volume between two spacial slices to show that $P^\mu$ is time-independent. However, this integral does not vanish a priori. Check the edit of my question.

Your problem is that you're looking at time-ordered  correlators. You need to look at Wightman functions, which are simply matrix elements. Inside of them, the stress tensor is conserved identically, i.e. you do not need to worry about other operator insertions.

Time-ordered correlators contain extra information at coincident points as compared to Wightman correlators, you cannot in general recover the former from the latter. Roughly speaking, $\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}(x)$ is not zero in time-ordered correlators since $\partial_\mu$ will hit the step functions in the definition of time-ordering, but this is glancing over a bunch of subtleties. If you have doubts about Wightman functions, note that they are boundary values of holomorphic functions; if they vanish in an open set, they must vanish everywhere.

I stress that I am interpreting $\langle \cdots \rangle$ as an expectation value with respect to the Poincaré invariant vacuum.
Barring mathematical technicalities, the conservation law can be stated as
$$ \partial_\mu \langle vac| A T^{\mu\nu}(x)B|vac\rangle = 0,$$
where $|vac\rangle$ is the Poincaré invariant vacuum and $A$ and $B$ any pair of operators in the algebra of local observables. Since the span of $A^\dagger|vac\rangle$ (and $B|vac\rangle$) is dense in the Hilbert space, the requirement above is equivalent to
$$ \partial_\mu  T^{\mu\nu}(x)= 0.$$
Finally, the conserved momentum operator is just the integral of the stress energy tensor as assumed in the original post.

So you conclude that $\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}(x)$ is the zero operator. But how is this consistent with the Schwinger-Dyson equation for the energy-momentum operator, which implies that $\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}(x) = 0$ only holds inside correlation functions with other insertions away from $x$?  Please check my edit, where I explain my issue in detail.

The SD equation you wrote already proves the thesis. Fix $x$ and consider the other  $x_n$ varying in a bounded region spatially separated from $x$. The right hand side of the DS equation is then zero. On the other hand the Reeh-Schlieder theorem proves that the span of the said observables applied to the vacuum is dense in the Hilbert space. Hence $\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0$. Notice that I am referring to Wightman functions and not time ordered n point functions.
